# Text overflowing from div on zoom in and out

Tags: css, html, zooming

I have a text inside the div. When I adjust the zoom level of the page, the text inside the div moves out of the div.I required the text to remain in the div as it is and not adjust the width of the div.

my div is :

```
    <div style="width: 463px; 
height: auto; 
min-height: 0px; 
overflow: visible; 
border: 3px dashed rgb(2, 158, 217); 
margin-left: 18px; 
max-width: 466px; 
color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
font-size: 12px; 
font-family: arimo; 
font-weight: 400; 
font-style: normal; 
text-align: start;
 white-space: nowrap; 
line-height: 1.231;
padding-left: 3.5px;" wrap="off" name="nowrap" id="changedtext5" class="textdrag">asdksjadksja&nbsp;kldjaslkjd&nbsp;jasdiwie&nbsp;qowyruasdasd&nbsp;kajskjd&nbsp;kjaskldjlka;sdioewyriosudfrds</div>
```

Comment: remove the width of the div in style tag

Comment: As a side note:
You shouldn't rely on zooming in or out in a browser to the page will look on different resolutions. The calculations done by browsers are unreliable and often rounded up, therefore some layout misbehavior may appear, despite having proper html/css syntax.

Comment: Yeah but the silly clients will not listen to this an ....they want ROI ..so much so that I need to even provide compatibility with IE7

Comment: Nothing pleasant, but to be honest, they are kinda in the right. Many people actually use zooming in and out and for them the website will be just broken. The only (painful) solution I could provide is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers and applying different styles in different zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:visible;` allows the text to escape the confines of the divider. Setting this to `overflow:hidden;` will hide any text which does manage to move outside of the divider.

I don't know if this is a solution you're after as it would end up hiding text.

If instead you want it to scroll, use `overflow-x:scroll;`.

Comment: Actually both the options are not favourable.I would like to have something which forces the text to stay inside the div without any spill and scrollbar.